# Cakephp3 check if user credentials are correct

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp.I just want to create a function(lets say API) that will get the username and password and will return if the credentials are correct or not.I have tried below code but i get the error message **Call to undefined method App\Controller _findUser()** .Please help

```
public function countLogin($username,$pass){

    if (empty($username) || empty($pass)) {
        return false;
    }
    echo $this->_findUser($username, $pass);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: That's because you haven't specified such a function findUser. Are you using Basic Authentication?

Comment: I want to use that but dont know the right approach

Comment: If you don't understand the error message I highly recommend you to get back to start and start learning the *very basics* of programming and how to deal with errors. Also what you try to do is already covered by the framework, do this tutorial -> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html Except the counting, but this is trivial.